# color dgrid cell based on cell value

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dgrid

I've got a dgrid and I'm trying to set the cell background color based on the value of the cell using a formatter function and css. The dgrid is located within a div with ID UnMarkedTicketGridDiv

formatter function:

```
formatPriority: function (item) {
            return = "<td class='" + item + "'>" + item + "</td>";
        },
```

css:

```
#UnMarkedTicketGridDiv td.NORM
{
    background-color:Green;
    color:Green;
}
```

Any idea why the cells arent getting colored green? I've verified the formatter function is being called, and there is an item named 'NORM' so that this class is being defined.  I think its something with getting the css selector right?

Here's the grid column definition:

```
grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, DijitRegistry]))({
                store: gridStore,
                columns: {
                    ID: "ID",
                    Ticket: "Ticket",
                    Street: "Address",
                    DateRcvdInt: { label: "Date Rcvd", formatter: this.formatDate },
                    WorkDateInt: { label: "Work Date", formatter: this.formatDate },
                    Priority: { label: "Priority", formatter: this.formatPriority },
                    Type: "Type",
                    Company: "Company"
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be rendering a `td` from a formatter; the table cell itself is the parent element for the output of the formatter.  There is probably a better way to do what you are trying to do, possibly using `renderCell`.  Can you also include your column definition in the question?

Comment: I put the column definition in above.  I also tried using a div tag in my formatter funciton instead of tds, but got the same result -- I'll look into the renderCell -- Thanks!

Comment: If you changed the type of tag, did you also change the selector in your CSS?  `td.NORM` wouldn't match anymore (and it's probably more appropriate to just leave off the tag from the selector anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the simplest way to do this would be to use `renderCell`, which gives you direct access to the cell:

```
Priority: {
    label: "Priority",
    renderCell: function (object, value, cell) {
        cell.className += " " + value;
        return document.createTextNode(value);
    }
}
```

Note that `renderCell` can return a node to be placed within the cell.  I use `createTextNode` rather than just setting `innerHTML` since the latter would be potentially susceptible to HTML injection from the data source.