# How to set cell color based on input parameter in DGrid

Tags: javascript, css, esri, dgrid

I am using DGrid to create my own legend in conjunction with an ESRI JS mapping application. I have created a layer in the map with a set of colors I created. I am trying to set the background color of specific cells to the colors I have previously chosen in the legend. I am not sure the easiest way to go about doing this. I have seen another thread for doing this, but the usage might be a little different than what I need: [color dgrid cell based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470289/color-dgrid-cell-based-on-cell-value). I am not sure what other information I need to provide.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and what results you got from doing that?

Comment: Hi Mike, so far I've just been trying to understand how rendercell works: var legendGrid = new Grid({columns : {    Color: 'Color',
            Range:{label:'Range',             renderCell:function(object, cell, value,node){              console.log(object)              
}
   }
}},"legendGrid"); I wasn't sure if the function in rendercell is a call back or not, like if the parameters are provided from a render cell handler.

Comment: I've also read the docs and can't seem to find exactly how to do what I want. I've also inspected the DOM on the browser to see if I can get access to a div or widget ID, but there is none for that type of element, only class identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like I needed a night to think it over, I was able to do what I wanted. I was able to set the style by using the value parameter and setting the background color with value.style = "background-color:color";

Thanks!